# DataFrame take every 3rd row and forward fill

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, quantitative-finance

I have a `DataFrame` with `'Date'` and `'Id'` in the index and `'Portfolio'` in the columns.  Values are weights of security within the portfolio.  Within the dates level of the index, I'd like to take every 3rd date and forward fill the security weight to the date subsequent to the next "every third" date.

#### Setup

This is a generic `DataFrame` producer. with `df` asigned at the end.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import uppercase

def generic_portfolio_df(start, end, freq, num_port, num_sec, seed=314):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    portfolios = pd.Index(['Portfolio {}'.format(i) for i in uppercase[:num_port]],
                          name='Portfolio')
    securities = ['s{:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(num_sec)]
    dates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=freq)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(dates) * num_sec, num_port),
                        index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, securities],
                                                         names=['Date', 'Id']),
                        columns=portfolios
                       ).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x / x.sum())    

df = generic_portfolio_df('2014-12-31', '2015-05-30', 'BM', 3, 5)
```

`df` looks like this:

```
Portfolio       Portfolio A  Portfolio B  Portfolio C
Date       Id                                        
2014-12-31 s00     0.326164     0.201597     0.085340
           s01     0.278614     0.314448     0.266392
           s02     0.258958     0.089224     0.293570
           s03     0.092760     0.262511     0.084208
           s04     0.043503     0.132221     0.270490
2015-01-30 s00     0.094124     0.041722     0.248013
           s01     0.197860     0.346862     0.265287
           s02     0.232504     0.261939     0.125719
           s03     0.193050     0.286359     0.337316
           s04     0.282462     0.063118     0.023664
2015-02-27 s00     0.266900     0.484163     0.074970
           s01     0.239319     0.083138     0.123289
           s02     0.067958     0.262626     0.262548
           s03     0.181974     0.108668     0.301149
           s04     0.243849     0.061405     0.238044
2015-03-31 s00     0.321438     0.149010     0.125168
           s01     0.217779     0.067209     0.040285
           s02     0.173066     0.293539     0.417372
           s03     0.048929     0.415637     0.216490
           s04     0.238788     0.074605     0.200685
2015-04-30 s00     0.089122     0.135514     0.234565
           s01     0.048235     0.028141     0.327739
           s02     0.026016     0.039664     0.073588
           s03     0.413139     0.397875     0.323671
           s04     0.423487     0.398807     0.040437
2015-05-29 s00     0.135831     0.071604     0.235099
           s01     0.240086     0.242436     0.131698
           s02     0.304451     0.380368     0.101653
           s03     0.213468     0.035276     0.372894
           s04     0.106164     0.270317     0.158656
```

#### Question

> Within the dates level of the index, I'd like to take every 3rd date and forward fill the security weight to the date subsequent to the next "every third" date.

I want it to look like:

```
Portfolio       Portfolio A  Portfolio B  Portfolio C
Date       Id                                        
2014-12-31 s00     0.326164     0.201597     0.085340
           s01     0.278614     0.314448     0.266392
           s02     0.258958     0.089224     0.293570
           s03     0.092760     0.262511     0.084208
           s04     0.043503     0.132221     0.270490
2015-01-30 s00     0.326164     0.201597     0.085340
           s01     0.278614     0.314448     0.266392
           s02     0.258958     0.089224     0.293570
           s03     0.092760     0.262511     0.084208
           s04     0.043503     0.132221     0.270490
2015-02-27 s00     0.326164     0.201597     0.085340
           s01     0.278614     0.314448     0.266392
           s02     0.258958     0.089224     0.293570
           s03     0.092760     0.262511     0.084208
           s04     0.043503     0.132221     0.270490
2015-03-31 s00     0.321438     0.149010     0.125168
           s01     0.217779     0.067209     0.040285
           s02     0.173066     0.293539     0.417372
           s03     0.048929     0.415637     0.216490
           s04     0.238788     0.074605     0.200685
2015-04-30 s00     0.321438     0.149010     0.125168
           s01     0.217779     0.067209     0.040285
           s02     0.173066     0.293539     0.417372
           s03     0.048929     0.415637     0.216490
           s04     0.238788     0.074605     0.200685
2015-05-29 s00     0.321438     0.149010     0.125168
           s01     0.217779     0.067209     0.040285
           s02     0.173066     0.293539     0.417372
           s03     0.048929     0.415637     0.216490
           s04     0.238788     0.074605     0.200685
```

#### Conclusion

Though I'm still interested in other's answers.  I chose Alexander's answer over my own for the following reason:

```
%%timeit
    df = generic_portfolio_df('2014-12-31', '2015-05-30', 'BM', 3, 5)
    df = df.unstack()
    df.iloc[3:] = np.nan
    df = df.ffill(limit=3).stack()

100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 ms per loop

%%timeit
    df = generic_portfolio_df('2014-12-31', '2015-05-30', 'BM', 3, 5)
    df0 = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[::3, :], :]
    diff = df.index.difference(df0.index)
    df.ix[diff] = np.nan
    df.groupby(level=1).ffill(limit=3)

100 loops, best of 3: 21 ms per loop
```

Apparently, using `stack` and `unstack` is more efficient.

Comment: Can you clarify 'fill the security weight to the date subsequent to the next "every third" date'? Your example appears to fill the each date past the third with the data from the third. My answer yields that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Create Boolean index of rows to delete (every third row is marked as False).
idx = len(df.unstack())
idx = [i % 3 > 0 for i in range(idx)]
>>> idx
[False, True, True, False, True, True]

# Unstack the dataframe so you just have a column of dates 
df = df.unstack()

# Delete those in the `idx` index.
df.loc[idx, :] = np.nan

# Forward fill the retained dates, and then restack your dataframe.
df = df.ffill(limit=3).stack()

>>> df.tail()
Portfolio       Portfolio A  Portfolio B  Portfolio C
Date       Id                                        
2015-05-29 s00     0.321438     0.149010     0.125168
           s01     0.217779     0.067209     0.040285
           s02     0.173066     0.293539     0.417372
           s03     0.048929     0.415637     0.216490
           s04     0.238788     0.074605     0.200685
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case (using 'BM' as frequency) a one-liner will do:

```
df2 = df.unstack().resample('3BM').first().resample('1BM').ffill(limit=3).stack()
```

Certainly, for other frequency string `freq` you can use `'3'+freq` and `'1'+freq` respectively.

**Update**

I've just noticed that the above code may add one day to the index (with `resample('3BM')`, so we have to additionally control the length of the data frame.

As for a general case, it can still be done in one line. For more readability I split it in two. First, I create an index of the lines in the unstacked data frame we want to keep:

```
idx = np.arange(np.ceil(len(df.unstack())/3), dtype = int)*3
df2 = df.unstack().iloc[idx].loc[df_t.index].fillna(method = 'ffill').stack()
```

It doesn't have the problem with adding unwanted rows and is more less equivalent to Alexander's answer. Anyway, I think Alexander's answer is clearer and more elegant.

Comment: I really like this answer.  My only problem is that it requires I know the frequency.  For example, I'd like to use this over arbitrary date series that may be irregular.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. It's still possible to write a one liner for a general case but it won't be that nice.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
df0 = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[::3, :], :]
diff = df.index.difference(df0.index)
df.ix[diff] = np.nan
df.groupby(level=1).ffill(limit=3)
```

This is almost identical to Alexander's answer.  This is what I used to produce the sample.

#### Highlights

- `pd.IndexSlice` I love this tool.  First two lines of code define the index to set as `np.nan` and does not require `unstack()`
- `groupby(level=1).ffill(limit=3)` again, don't have to manipulate in `unstacked()` mode
- `limit=3` is required though it wasn't obvious with example I gave.  It may be the case that an `'Id'` may exist early on and fall out of a portfolio.  If this were to happen, the rest of the column would be `'NaN'` and subject to `ffill`.  `limit=3` prevents this.